# A non-continuous map between the cone over a space and a similar space to it.

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

> Let $X=\{(k,0) \mid k =0,1,\dots\} \subset \Bbb R^2$ and consider the cone $CX$ over $X$. Let $C'X$ be the subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ obtained by taking the union of the line segments from $(k,0)$ to $(0,1)$ for all $k=0,1,\dots$ Let $q:X \times I \to CX, ((k,0),t) \mapsto[((k,0),t)]$ be the quotient map and $h: X \times I \to C'X$ the map sending $((k,0),t) \mapsto t(0,1)+(1-t)(k,0)$. Show that the *inverse* $\tilde{h}^{-1}$ of the induced map $\tilde h:CX \to C'X$ sending $[((k,0),t)] \mapsto t(0,1)+(1-t)(k,0)$ is *not* continuous.

I've tried to figure out what is the problem coming up with continuity for the inverse, but can't figure it out. The spaces look very similar except that the "vertex" of $C'X$ is the point $(0,1)$ which is different from the vertex of $CX$. Is this what's causing the discontinuity here or am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: Consider the sequence $[((k,0),1-1/\sqrt{k})]\in CX$. These tend to the vertex of $CX$, but are sent by the map to $(\sqrt{k},1-1/\sqrt{k})$.

Comment: How did you come up with this sequence? @user85667

Comment: I think on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_(topology)) it's the other way around, there the vertex is at $t=0$ or am I mistaken? However, in this exercise the vertex should clearly be at $[(k,0),1]$. The important insight is that in $CX$ we only need $t\rightarrow 1$, no matter the $k$, while in $C'X$ we need both coordinates to tend to $(0,1)$, jointly. There are many suitable sequences $(t_n,k_n)$, as long as $t_n\rightarrow 1$ and $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-t_n)k_n>0$. For example, you can also take $(t_n,k_n)=(1-\frac{1}{n},n)$ or $(1-\frac{1}{\ln(n)},n)$...

Comment: $\tilde h^{-1}$ is continuous iff $\tilde h$ is a homeomorphism. This was treated in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2973093. Note that that $X$ is not compact.